# Containment in sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I have a collection of items, each of which belongs in exactly three sets.  Each set contains exactly $m$ items.  Given numbers $x_2, x_3$, how can I choose $k$ sets such that $x_2$ of the items are contained in two sets and $x_3$ of the items are contained in three sets?  Also, when is it possible to do this?

Alternatively, I have a bipartite graph.  Each vertex on the left has degree $m$, and each vertex on the right has degree $3$.  How can I mark $k$ vertices on the left such that $x_2$ vertices are adjacent to $2$ marked vertices and $x_3$ vertices are adjacent to $3$ marked vertices?

Alternatively, how might I generate an $n$-vertex graph that contains $k$ edges, $x_3$ triangles, and $x_2$ open triads?

Thanks!

Comment: It feels like it would be easier to get a hold of this if you think of it as choosing which sets _not_ to mark. Then you know how many items not to hit at all, and how many items to hit exactly once.

Comment: Interesting point.  I'll think about that, thank you.

Comment: Even so, it feels like a hard problem. At least without the restriction that each set has exactly $m$ members, I don't think there can be a polynomial-time solution unless P=NP (it feels like there should be a Turing reduction from 3SAT). And that restriction feels like it ought to be possible to reduce it away.

Comment: Well that is disappointing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: If you allow even two different sizes $m_1$ and $m_2$ of the sets, then whether a solution exists cannot be decided in polynomial time unless P=NP.

I will prove this by Turing reduction from 3CNF-SAT.

The input is a 3CNF formula. We can assume without loss of generality that every variable appears as many times as a positive atom as it appears as a negative atom; otherwise add some clauses of the form $(A\lor \neg A \lor \neg A)$ or $(A\lor A\lor \neg A)$ until things balance. This increases the size of the the formula at most by a factor of 4.

Let $n$ be the number of clauses in the balanced 3CNF, and let $p$, $q$, and $r$ be the three first primes larger than $3n$. Thanks to Bertrand's postulate neither prime is larger than $24n$.

We're going to construct a family of $n+1$ instances of your problem such that the 3CNF is satisfiable exactly if one of the instances have a solution. These instances differ only in the value of $x_2$. They have the same set of $np+3nq+nr < 120n^2$ "items" and $6n$ "sets" of size $m_1=p+2q$ or $m_2=q+r$.

The $np+3nq+nr$ items will be assigned in "groups" of size $p$, $q$ or $r$, such that every item in each group is in the same sets. Then, when we know now many items are covered by a certain number of sets, the Chinese Remainder Theorem allows us to know how many groups of each kind they are.

There will be $3n$ "atom sets", each corresponding to an *occurrence* of an atom in the CNF. Intuitively, the atom set will be *chosen* if the atom is *false*.

Each *clause* in the CNF will be represented as a $p$-group, which is connected to the atom sets in the clause. We're going to require that the number of chosen sets covering the $p$-group is *different from 3*, which corresponds to the clause being true.

The we need to add something that guarantees that the different atom sets for each variable are chosen or not-chosen in a consistent way. Arrange the atom sets for each variable in a circle such that positive occurrences alternate with negative ones. For each pair of neighboring sets, add a $q$-group whose items are in the two atom sets. We're going to require that each $q$ group is covered by exactly one of the atom sets.

The $q$-group is only connected to *two* atom sets, so in order to give it the right degree we also connect it to a "helper" set, which we will make sure is always chosen. The helper set will also connect to an $r$-group, with three helper sets sharing each $r$-group. (This is always possible because there are $3n$ helper sets, so there will be $n$ $r$-groups). We will require that each $r$ group is covered by *exactly three* chosen sets. That forces all of the helper sets to be chosen, so we can require that each $q$-group is covered by exactly 2 chosen sets.

This describes all of the items. The only thing we don't know is how many of the $p$ groups will have 2 chosen sets (rather than 0 or 1), so we need to construct one instance of the problem for each $i\in\{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}$. This instance will have
$$ x_2 = 3nq + ip \qquad x_3 = nr \qquad k = 3n/2 + 3n$$

If one of these instances have a solution, it will correspond to a satisfying truth assignment for the 3CNF. Conversely, if we can satisfy the 3CNF we can also solve the corresponding problem instance.

Each of the problem instances has a size that is polynomial in the size of the 3CNF, and there are polynomially many of them. So if we had a polynomial solver for your problem (extended to allow to different $m$s), we could use that to decide 3CNF-SAT in polynomial time.